Cross-border workers stay visa in Germany
There is so much info about cross-border workers. But I couldn't find an answer to my question yet.
As a non-EU citizen, can I work in Luxembourg & live in Germany? The Internet says "Yes".
But for that I need to apply for a work permit/visa in Luxembourg. And what about in Germany? What kind of visa should I get to stay in Germany? Can I show my job contract in Luxembourg to apply for a residence visa in Germany? If so, how was your experience, and please share some links on this topic.
So my concern is not about getting a visa for Luxembourg. My concern is about visa to Germany to live as a non-EU citizen


As a non-EU citizen, can I work in Luxembourg & live in Germany?
...
Can I show my job contract in Luxembourg to apply for a stay visa in Germany?

Yes, the German Residence Act (§5 (1)(1)) only requires that the foreigner’s subsistence is secure.
There is no extra condition that the source of income must come from inside Germany or what form that income must be.

Sources:

Working in Luxembourg as a third-country national and cross-border worker - Guichet.lu - Luxembourg


Third-country nationals legally resident in another Member State of the European Union (EU) or in a country treated as such (Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway or Switzerland) and wishing to work in Luxembourg without residing there must, in principle, obtain a work permit before commencing work in Luxembourg.
Work permit application

a copy of an authorisation to stay issued by another EU Member State or country treated as such (Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway or Switzerland);



Residence Act (AufenthG)

§5 - General prerequisites for granting residence titles




(1) As a rule, a residence title is granted subject to the following conditions:

1.  the foreigner’s subsistence is secure;
1a.  the foreigner’s identity, and if he or she is not entitled to return to another state, nationality are established,
2.  there is no public interest in expelling the foreigner,
3.  if the foreigner is not entitled to a residence title, the foreigner’s stay does not threaten or jeopardise the interests of the Federal Republic of Germany for any other reason, and
4.  the passport obligation laid down in section 3 is met.


